# Files keeps disappearing after an early commit had removed them

Tags: mercurial

Another questions regarding (binary) files in a repo.

I need them for local access(they are db binaries). Someone removed them from the repo in an early commit. I put them back into the repo, but after a commit, they disappear again.

IN my bitbucket dashboard, the early removal said `Binary file removed.` so I believe it is done through `hg remove`.

I am ignoring this directory. But why do the files keep disappearing?

```
syntax: glob
... more rules

project/directory/mongodb-linux/*
```

I am ignoring other directories but they are just fine...

How can I prevent them from disappearing and anyone who pull from this repo again (already have the binaries in-place) can keep theirs as well?

Thanks.

Comment: what does `hg stat` tell you about the file? Btw: Mercurial doesn't distinguish between binary and text files the same way CVS did, so no need to mention it actually.

Comment: I am guessing you want me to add them back first? But for one thing, `hg stat` tells me `! project/apps/__init__.py`

Comment: @0xC0000022L  I did hg stat on those files but nothing appears. Thanks.